# Getting the last entry in a list in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the last entry in a list, and then compare that entry to another entry from a different list.

```
ExpertiseList=['5', '9', '10']
DifficultyList=['1', '2', '7']
```

I have tried:

```
if ExpertiseList[len(ExpertiseList-1)]>=DifficultyList[len(DifficultyList)-1]:
    print("Solved")
```

However I get the error message.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: You can just use [-1] as the list index to return the last item in a list.  Your list also appears to be of strings, so you might need to do another type conversion depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

you wrote `len(ExpertiseList-1)` instead of `len(ExpertiseList) - 1`. Although note that negative-indexing gives you elements from the right side of the list, so `some_lst[-1]` is the last element.

The error message is telling you that you tried to use the subtraction operator (`-`) between a list and an int, and that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

`len(ExpertiseList-1)` should be `len(ExpertiseList) - 1` or otherwise you are trying to subtract integer from the list

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to offer any substantial points made over the answer posted by @AdamSmith.

Comment: @ChristianDean:  Doesn't make it any less *wrong*, either.

Comment: @Makoto That's true. I was just trying to find a way to make my point without appearing overly condescending. I wasn't trying to imply that copying other answers is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to get the last element of a list. In python, indexing and slicing is very powerful. The `[ ]` operator accepts three arguments, separated by colons: `[start:end:step]`, with the start index being inclusive and the end index exclusive. When one argument is given, it returns the corresponding amount element, else it returns a slice of the list.

The indexes can also be negative. A negative index indexes from the end of the list, instead of the start, e.g. `[-1]` gives the last element in the list, `[-2]` the second to last etc.

I will give some examples of slicing here, just for fun :

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
l[-1] # 5
l[:-1] # [0,1,2,3,4]
l[::2] # [0,2,4]
l[::-1] # [5,4,3,2,1,0]
l[-1:1:-2] # [5,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

That "-1" in the first list is inside de len function, you must place it after the closing ")".

```
if ExpertiseList[len(ExpertiseList)-1]>=DifficultyList[len(DifficultyList)-1]:
print("Solved")
```